# Updating a column in rails saves other column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, update-attributes

When i update a column in rails it also updates other column.
"Post.new" and after saving it i did a 
post.title = "sample"
and i doing a 
"post.save"
Here my other column is also been updated.how to solve this

Comment: What is name of column is updated?

Comment: other colunm is "column_X" in which is in association with table Post.

Answer (score 0):

The other column which will get updated on save along with the columns you want to update is "updated_at" or "updated_on". Is you column named after this? If yes, you have to change these column names for smooth rails operation.

Comment: It is better to `rails g model MyModel --no-timestamps` or remove `t.timestamps` from migration file

Comment: other column is "column_X" in which is in association with table Post. so whenever i update this table "post" it updates a specific column in table_2